# Where can I find chinese (Mandarin) books in Paris?

Tags: china, paris, study, french-citizens, chinese-language

Ni Hao everyone

I am searching for Mandarin learning books (or used books if possible) in Paris please.

Thanks in advance !

谢谢

Best regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Librairie Le Phénix,
  72 boulevard de Sébastopol
  75003 Paris specialises in Chinese books. Look at https://www.librairielephenix.fr/
- https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibert_Jeune has many choices as well and likely has Mandarin learning books. Call them to check.
- http://amazon.fr/

Comment: I would think that large libraries like the FNAC have chinese learning books

Comment: @Max yes, pretty sure.

Comment: Do you know if there is an area in Paris where Chinese shops cluster together? I know the area in Amsterdam has several Chinese bookshops as well, also with books aiming at learners of Chinese. I have never been in such an area in Paris, so I would not know if one is there.

Comment: @Willeke Chinese shops typically cluster in the Paris Chinatown but idk about Chinese libraries.

Comment: This one https://www.you-feng.com/librairies.php (the rue beaudricourt one) is in the Paris 'chinatown'.